# Understanding EPSG in WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, mapping, well-known-text, datum

I notice several EPSG codes in one WKT. At the first glance it almost is non-intuitive to see so many EPSG codes linked to a single EPSG.

Can someone explain each line of the following WKTs for `EPSG:5070` and `EPSG:4326`?

[EPSG: 5070](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/epsg-5070/)

[image]

[EPSG: 4326](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/)

[image]

Comment: ESPG is not just for the coordinate system. Each component has a code. The first two codes in your 1st example are for the spheroid GRS 80 [EPSG 7019](http://epsg.io/7019-ellipsoid) and the datum NAD 83 [EPSG 6269](http://epsg.io/6269-datum).

Comment: It might help to check this page and follow the links https://epsg.org/crs_5070/NAD83-Conus-Albers.html? The manual of the web app  https://epsg.org/template/IOGP/downloads/user_manual_v5.2.1.pdf could be useful as well.

Answer (score 6):

For a full understanding see the specifications:

https://www.ogc.org/standards/wkt-crs

Interestingly, if you look at the EPSG registry (https://epsg.org/home.html) WKT2 definitions of those two CRS then you see that almost every line has an associated EPSG code

https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/5070

```
PROJCRS["NAD83 / Conus Albers",
  BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
      ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],
        ID["EPSG",7019]],
      ID["EPSG",6269]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
      ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]],
      ID["EPSG",8901]],
    ID["EPSG",4269]],
  CONVERSION["Conus Albers",
    METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
      ID["EPSG",9822]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,
      ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
      ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.5,
      ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,
      ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]],
    PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
      LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],
    PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
      LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],
    ID["EPSG",5068]],
  CS[Cartesian,2,
    ID["EPSG",4499]],
  AXIS["Easting (X)",east,
    ORDER[1]],
  AXIS["Northing (Y)",north,
    ORDER[2]],
  LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],
  USAGE[SCOPE["Data analysis and small scale data presentation for contiguous lower 48 states."],AREA["United States (USA) - CONUS onshore - Alabama; Arizona; Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; Georgia; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; Wyoming."],
  BBOX[24.41,-124.79,49.38,-66.91]],
ID["EPSG",5070]]
```

https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/4326

```
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
  ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
     MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)",
       ID["EPSG",1166]],
     MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)",
       ID["EPSG",1152]],
     MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)",
       ID["EPSG",1153]],
     MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)",
       ID["EPSG",1154]],
     MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)",
       ID["EPSG",1155]],
     MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)",
       ID["EPSG",1156]],
     ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
      LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]],
      ID["EPSG",7030]],
     ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2],
    ID["EPSG",6326]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]],
    ID["EPSG",8901]],
  CS[ellipsoidal,2,
    ID["EPSG",6422]],
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
    ORDER[1]],
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
    ORDER[2]],
  ANGLEUNIT["degree (supplier to define representation)",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]],
  USAGE[SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],AREA["World."],
  BBOX[-90.00,-180.00,90.00,180.00]],
ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

You can look-up the respective codes in the registry for example `EPSG",9122` is a transformation (NAD83(CSRS)v2 to NAD83(CSRS)v4 (1)): https://epsg.org/transformation/wkt/id/9122